# requestAnimationFrame() is causing a major slow down. Why?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `requestAnimationFrame` and after a short while it starts to lag. Is this normal?

Here is the code:

```
var arrowNumberUpValue = Number(arrowUpValue) * 100
console.log(typeof arrowNumberUpValue === 'number')

function up_svg(){

    if(arrowNumberUpValue <= 100 && arrowNumberUpValue >= 50){
        arrowNumberUpValue = arrowNumberUpValue - 1
        console.log(arrowNumberUpValue)
        arrowUpFirst.style.transform = "scale(" + (arrowNumberUpValue/100).toPrecision(1) + ") rotate(-90deg)"
        arrowUpSecond.style.transform = "scale(" + (arrowNumberUpValue/100).toPrecision(1) + ") rotate(-90deg)"
        arrowUpThird.style.transform = "scale(" + (arrowNumberUpValue/100).toPrecision(1) + ") rotate(-90deg)"
        arrowUpFourth.style.transform = "scale(" + (arrowNumberUpValue/100).toPrecision(1) + ") rotate(-90deg)"
    } 
    if(arrowNumberUpValue < 50){
        for(;arrowNumberUpValue < 100;){
            arrowNumberUpValue = arrowNumberUpValue + 1
            console.log(arrowNumberUpValue)
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(up_svg)
}

up_svg()
```

Comment: Provide a working example please.

Comment: This is just a fragment of a greater piece. This small fragment is supposed to cause the arrow to pulsate. It does all that, but after a while it starts to lag.

Comment: Ok. Then, why do you use a for like that? Why not `for(; arrowNumberUpValue < 100; arrowNumberUpValue++) console.log(arrowNumberUpValue);`

Comment: Ok. True, I should've used ++ instead of calculating the value inside the loop. But that still does not help.

Comment: There is no need for that loop - all it does is set arrowNumberUpValue back to 100, which you can do by simply setting it directly to 100 :)

Comment: What about css animations? Seems like what you want can be accomplished by adding/removing classes with the `animation` property.

Comment: xs0 I have tried running it with your suggestion but it did not fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Edit: after the back and forth in the comments, it looks like the problem was using transition: 1s together with updating the transform every frame.

This version removes the need for transition:

```
var scaling = 1.0;  
function up_svg() {
    arrowNumberUpValue = arrowNumberUpValue <= 50 ? 100 : arrowNumberUpValue - 1;
    var target = arrowNumberUpValue / 100;
    var speed = 3/60;
    scaling = scaling * (1 - speed) + target * (speed);

    var trans = "scale(" + scaling.toPrecision(4) + ") rotate(-90deg)";
    arrowUpFirst.style.transform = trans;
    arrowUpSecond.style.transform = trans;
    arrowUpThird.style.transform = trans;
    arrowUpFourth.style.transform = trans;

    requestAnimationFrame(up_svg)
}
up_svg()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried taking out the console output but it does not rectify the problem

Comment: Well, are you sure this piece is the source of the problem? Could be it's something else that's real slow / using much memory /etc, but you only see it in the arrows..

Comment: Well when I exclude the function with the animation code everything runs smooth. Presumably I can run this animation without any code but still I'm confused to why this is not running as it should

Comment: It's indeed strange - people run 3d game engines in javascript, and this is faaaar simpler, so I'd expect it to run smoothly on its own.. Try [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/js-execution) to maybe see where the time is going?

Comment: I have noticed that when running the code on chrome, there is no lagging, only with mozilla. I have output the values through document.innerHTML and I could see that the values in mozilla begin to 'stutter' and on chrome the changing value is very smooth. Any clue why?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.. Can you maybe create a runnable snippet that contains the arrows etc., so we can take a look at it? (edit question, then there's a button for creating code snippets, or just press Ctrl-M)

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, that toPrecision(1) seems somewhat suspicious.. can you try with toPrecision(4)?

Comment: here is a quick snippet. Open the code in chrome and firefox, you will notice that after a while the code on firefox begins to lose smoothness. https://jsfiddle.net/b6kezaku/2/

Comment: Open the codes at the same time in both browsers, reduce size of them, place them aside to each other and run them, after a while, you will begin to notice the difference

Comment: On my computer, nothing happens in terms of losing smoothness.. However, I did notice you're using transition: 1s, and at the same time you're updating the transform 60 times a second.. Not sure it's related, but here's a version that doesn't use transition: https://jsfiddle.net/b6kezaku/4/ . Is it any better?

Comment: Excellent.. updated the answer to reflect new findings :) Please accept it if you feel the problem is solved..

Comment: xs0 Yes, the problem is solved, thanks to your advice I realised that my understanding of the requestAnimationFrame was not fully comprehended. Did not know that its default frequency for the loop was 60/1s. This fact explains everything now ;) Still new to this method and programming(javascript) in general ;) This is still a learning process. Thanks again xs0 :)